# tableview cell has wrong background layer after reuse

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UIView extension which makes a gradient background from two colours. I use this so I add a nice background to my custom tableView cells. But after the reuse, the colour is always wrong (unlike the data inside which is correct). It's not like a plain background colour, and all colors depend on the value from the fetched data. After reuse, the background is always random from the previously generated cells (and their backgrounds).

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    var imgTitle = ""
    var color = UIColor()
    let title = fetchedUV[indexPath.row].value
    if title >  11 {
        imgTitle = "flame"
        color = UIColor.purple
        cell.setGradientBackground(colorOne: .white, colorTwo: color)
    } else if title >= 8 {
        imgTitle = "sun-protection"
        color = UIColor.red
        cell.setGradientBackground(colorOne: .white, colorTwo: color)
    } else if title >= 6 {
        imgTitle = "sunbed"
        color = UIColor.orange
        cell.setGradientBackground(colorOne: .white, colorTwo: color)
    } else if title >= 3 {
        imgTitle = "sunglasses"
        color = UIColor.yellow
        cell.setGradientBackground(colorOne: .white, colorTwo: color)
    } else {
        imgTitle = "ok"
        color = UIColor.green
        cell.setGradientBackground(colorOne: .white, colorTwo: color)
    }

    colors.append(color)
    let UVValue = String(describing: title)

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    cell.commonInit(imgTitle, title: UVValue, time: fetchedUV[indexPath.row].dateIso)

    cell.logoImage.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.frame.height) / 2
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.height/2


    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
    //cell.setGradientBackground(colorOne: .white, colorTwo: color)

    return cell
}

extension UIView {
    func setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `setGradientBackground(colorOne:,colorTwo:)` method actually do? Why do you call it twice per cell?

Comment: I forgot to uncomment it while I was debugging. It makes the view have a gradient background from two colors starting top left, ending top right while blending the colors inbetween.

Comment: There's your problem. You keep adding more and more layers as each cell gets reused.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Instead of setting cell.setGradientBackground each Time cell is dequeued , insert a check that do the cell already had that sublayer or not ? , Can you show setGradientBackground func ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had find and remove the previously added layer (the CAGradientLayer because it can remove any other layer as well). Do the checks and add another layer if its needed. I also changed the function so the layer now has a name. (thanks to iOS Geek for the suggestion)

```
for sublayer in cell.layer.sublayers! {
                if let _ = sublayer as? CAGradientLayer {
                    if sublayer.name == name {
                        print("Cell deque again")
                    } else {
                        sublayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                        cell.setGradientBackground0(colorOne: .white, colorTwo: color, name: name)
                    }
                } else {
                    cell.setGradientBackground0(colorOne: .white, colorTwo: color, name: name)
            }
        }

extension UIView {
func setGradientBackground0(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor, name: String) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.name = name
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

I'll leave this just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Just for an Example try looking at this

```
extension UIView
{
    //This func will add gradient backgroung
    //Just sample one
    func setGradientBackground()
    {
        //Colors
        let colorTop =  UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 149.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 94.0/255.0, blue: 58.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

        //Set Gradient layer
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

        //Colors
        gradientLayer.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]

        //Locations
        gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]

        //Here is the main Play
        //Set Layer name so can be identified while Dequeuing cell
        gradientLayer.name = "layerName"

        //Set bounds
        gradientLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds

        //Insert Layer
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

Now in CellForRowAt of TableView

```
//Setting cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        //Get all the sublayers of cell
        for sublayer in cell.layer.sublayers!
        {
            //Check that sublayer is Already Added or not
            if sublayer.name == "layerName"
            {
                //Sublayer already added
                //Print already Added
                print("Cell Deque again")
            }
            else
            {
                //Sublayer is not added yet
                //Time to add Gradient Background
                cell.setGradientBackground()
                print("Layer Added")
            }
        }

        //setting title
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

Hope it Helps , You can Name a layer that is being added as SubLayer and when Adding it to Cell as it gets Deque again and again so you must see that layer is not override on previous added layer

Comment: Not working since you need to remove the gradient layer first (it still overrides if its not removed).

Comment: I do not think so I had written some checks for that while I am dequeuing the cell , that if sublayer contains "layer Added" it will skip adding again and if not added gradient color will be set, Secondly if a layer already Exists in sublayer we do not need to add It again we can simply use the same layer, Seems like something is not clear can you explain what issue you faced

Comment: Yes but if another layer is added, now there are two layers and it will use one of those. The fix for this can be using the same gradientLayer and changing the colors, but since the function is working by adding a new layer to the view, it was easier for me to find that layer, remove it and add the correct one.
I added the solution as the answer.